# Horizontal buttons with max width and weight

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-screen-support, android-layout-weight

I want to have two horizontal buttons with the first one taking 60 % of the layout width and the second one taking 40%. Both buttons have a max width for very large screens and in that case it has to be left aligned.

I tried with LinearLayout as shown below. But I am not sure if max width would work with weight. What is the correct way of implementing this?

```
 <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:weightSum="1"
     app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/eventTitle">

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/one"
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_height="80dp"
         android:layout_weight=".6"
         android:maxWidth="547dp"
         android:text="One" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/two"
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_height="80dp"
         android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
         android:layout_weight=".4"
         android:maxWidth="349dp"
         android:text="Two" />
```

Comment: If you needed a different layout for larger screens, then why not create a new layout for the dimension? https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute `maxWidth` should be set in your LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:weightSum="1"
     android:maxWidth="896dp"
     app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/eventTitle">
```

Remove it from your child views and the corresponding weight will be used.

Answer (score 1):

I think the requirement is like below image :

[image: Click here two view the ConstraintLayout]

Here is code to achieve the same :

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.6" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```